# Storing computed values to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying some online problems. I programmed how to solve the greatest palindrome product of 2 two-digit numbers. For example 91*99=9009. I managed to do it by using the recursive function but I wonder how can i do it using arrays like this one?

```
product[0]=9;
product[1]=0;
product[2]=0;
product[3]=9;
```

or if the computed product is 969;

```
product[0]=9;
product[1]=6;
product[2]=9;
```

Then I will output it starting from the last index to the first index then test if its equal to the original number.

EDIT:
My question is, how can i store the computed product to an array?

Comment: You should edit the question name too.

Comment: It's not clear why you think using an array will help. You can make an iterative solution without using an array. Hint: `String.charAt`.

Comment: If its a palindrome, then just add the values inside a `List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>(); while (product > 0) {li.add(product % 10); product /= 10;}` and test if the `li` list is a palindrome array.

Comment: Are you asking how to split a number in digits ?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to solve ?: http://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Comment: Yeah that's the one but I already managed to do it using a formula similar to Luiggi Mendoza's comment. Now i want to solve it in a different way by storing it in an array, then reading it backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to solve that Project Euler problem using arrays. But if you're fixated on it, then there is a simple algorithm to convert an array of digits into a number. Just do this:

```
int number = 0;
int number_2 = 0;

//going forwards:
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    number = number * 10 + array[i];
}

//going backwards:
for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    number_2 = number_2 * 10 + array[i];
}

if (number == number_2)
{
    //you have a palindrome
}
```

It's not the most efficient method, I know (@Nandkumar's is faster), but it's really really simple, that's what I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `String` from the integer product.

Comment: I removed the down vote and the reason of down vote was just converting into `String` would not answer his `modified` question as well. `EDIT: My question is, how can i store the computed product to an array?`

Comment: Strings have char arrays so all you need do is request that representation from the String class.  I was trying not to flat out solve this homework like question for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I won't writ you code, because it looks like an assignment, but I'll give you a hint.

Convert the int into a string first.

Characters in a string are very much like arrays, so it'll be easy to convert the string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the number into an array you can try this...

```
Char [] product = String.valueOf("969").toCharArray();
```

Comment: OP is not asking how to check if an array is a palindrome.

Comment: Then delete the answer as it is no longer relevant to the question being asked.  Not answering the question is a perfectly valid reason for a downvote.

Comment: How do you propose the OP get the String literal "939" from the product of two integer variables?

Comment: I accepted the edit and `939` was just an example which I corrected. But generally speaking if the question is changed after it was answered; why the answer is being down-voted? I don't see the logic here David.

Comment: As per the SO mechanics, you are allowed to change your upvote/downvote to an answer after 5 minutes *only* if an edit is made.  Thus, the idea that you can change your opinion of an answer (downvote or upvote) if an edit happens is very natural.  I removed my downvote since you've changed your answer.. it's amazing that you would go downvote my correct answer just out of spite...

Answer (score 0):

Provide your product to `String.valueOf(int)`, it will be converted to string and then convert it into array using `String.toCharArray()` like

```
boolean palindrome = true;
int product = 9009; // or any calculated number
char str[] = String.valueOf(product).toCharArray();

for(int i=0,j=str.length-1; i!=j ;i++,j--) {
    if(str[i] == str[j]){
        continue;
    } else {
        palindrome = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh. I see. I was lacking .toCharArray(). I just started learning java like 2 weeeks ago and I'm still wondering how you guys manage to figure out the right codes. thanks!

Comment: @DavidCowden : i and j are local to loop and within scope of loop, so how would u conclude whether product is palindrome or not?